# Changing decimal separator with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal

I work with teams from multiple countries and sometimes I receive excel files that have another decimal separator than the one I use. Is there any formula to do that? I certainly could use a macro, but a formula would be much easier because I am not the only person in my company in need of this and a macro would be too complicated for the general Joe Public.

Please keep in mind that I may have multiple separators in the same number, for example, 3.000.000,00 has 2 points for the thousands and millions, and the comma for the decimals. That is why I am finding it difficult.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the `NUMBERVALUE` function.

For example, if I have 3.000.000,00 in cell `A1` I can enter `=NUMBERVALUE(A1,",",".")` in cell `B1` to get the number

The [arguments](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879) are

- Text. The text to convert to a number.
- Decimal_separator. The character used to separate the
  integer and fractional part of the result.
- Group_separator. The character used to separate groupings
  of numbers, such as thousands from hundreds and millions from
  thousands.

This is available in Excel 2013 and later or Excel 2011 for Mac or later.  I work in an Excel 2013 environment and sometimes forget to qualify my answers with that.  Thanks to [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy) for pointing out the version requirements.

Specifically:

Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for Mac 2011, Excel Online, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone, Excel for Android tablets, Excel Mobile, Excel for Android phones

Comment: This is better than mine.  Great job. It would be the one I used, now that I know about it. :)

Comment: FYI, Excel 2013 and later.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! I will be using this pretty often. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!!!!! My team has been looking for that for a loooooong time!

Comment: @DougGlancy unlike what Microsoft indicates at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/numbervalue-function-1b05c8cf-2bfa-4437-af70-596c7ea7d879 [screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20240116185105if_/https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/111/767/118/252/281/302/original/0f64248363eb35f3.png) as my Excel 2011 on Mac does not support the `=NUMBERVALUE()` function, see [this screenshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20240116185131if_/https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/111/767/128/278/987/746/original/10af6025297caa1a.png).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),",",".")
```

[image]

Then apply the proper formatting.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, nice. I was trying `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".",1),".",",")`. which just returns all commas.  What's the `- -` before it do?

Comment: @BruceWayne the Substitute function returns a string, so the `--` will change the returned text to a number.  But in all honesty Soulfire's answer is better.

Comment: Soulfire's solution is nice indeed, but this would (in combination with `TEXT()`) still be the way to go if the conversion would be the other way, from number to text.

Comment: In my case, without the -- did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This indeed works on Excel 2011 on one of my Macs ( where `=NUMBERVALUE(B1)` returns `#NAME?`, see the comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925721/changing-decimal-separator-with-formula#comment137206197_35925870 )

I like the simplicity of the `--` solution. Based on it, I tried `0+` which also works fine.