# Region independent number concatenation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an automation in excel wherein an sql query is built which is then executed on MS Access database using a macro.

Part of this sql query in Excel is something like:  `'12.3' as column_amount`
and many such parts concatenated together form the sql query.

This part of sql query is calculated in Excel as: `= "'" & A1 & "' as column_amount"`
This cell A1 always contains a number, could be a decimal number as well.

Now, the challenge is formatting of cell A1 is region dependent and could be `12.3` or `12,3` dependening on PC's region settings. When it is `12,3` (comma instead of decimal) the sql query part also takes comma, i.e. `'12,3' as column_amount` . However, this is not an ideal case because MS Access needs to store `12.3` as a number and should receive decimal in place of decimal.

How do I make sure in Excel that regardless of regional settings, `12,3` is also concatenated as `12.3`?

Excel version 2010

PS: It is very strange in my case that it was working absolutely fine for last several months in my automation and I can't figure out what changed recently leading to this issue.

Comment: Use `TEXT` perhaps.

Comment: That won't help, TEXT will need a format and that format will again be dependent on region settings

Comment: Yes, regardless of region settings, i.e. regardless of whether it is 12.3 or 12,3 I want 12.3 in concatenation ('12.3' as column_amount)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925721/changing-decimal-separator-with-formula

Comment: `="'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")&"' as column_amount"` should work fine

Comment: Yeah, using SUBSTITUTE trickery will be my last option because then there can be dot or space for thousand separators which will be another thing to deal with (e.g. Norway uses space for thousand sep and Germany uses dot.

Comment: I am hoping for some solution where excel reads a number as a number independent of region, i.e. with a decimal. For example, even if I use VALUE, it still concatenates with a comma

Comment: But since Access is MS I guess it may still work feeding it values like `1200000.3` wouldn't it? The values from Excel are numberformatted but don't actually contain commas for thousand sep.

Comment: Probably right, could then use substitution if there is no proper solution