# How do you set custom formatting in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting

I wish to have a different display depending on the specified format.

The number I am using as example value is `1234567.89`.

#### Format 1: European with space as thousand-separtor and Dollar-symbol at the end

With a cell format set as `# ##0,00 $`:

- desired output expected as `1 234 567,89 $`
- but was appearing as `1,2 34,568 $` (no decimal separator and commas as thousand-separator)

#### Format 2: US with Dollar-symbol prefixed

With a cell format set as `$#,##0.00`:

- desired output expected as `$1,234,567.89`
- and was as expected

**Only this works!**

#### Format 3: European with Dollar-symbol at the end

With a cell format set as `#.##0,00 $`:

- desired output expected as `1.234.567,89 $`
- but was appearing as `1234567.89000 $` (no thousand-separator and wrong decimal-separator with 5 additional decimals digits)

How can I make it so that the cell is formatted correctly?

Comment: Without looking into this too much, you do realize you are mixing the dot and comma around? What is your system's decimal delimiter?

Comment: group seperator is ',' and decimal separator is '.', can this be set in the document programatically?

Comment: The thousands separator and decimal can be changed in the Excel environment, but not for a particular document.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to customize the format of each cell based on the custom formatting I wanted to display. I will just format everything the same and let excel decide how to display it.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on Ron Rosenfeld's answering comment.

There are 2 ways to deal with this **local number formatting** in Excel:

### Change the decimal and thousands separator Excel-wide

**Warning:** This will apply globally for all workbooks.

It is described in following articles:

- How To Geek: [How to Change Excel’s Decimal Separators from Periods to Commas](https://www.howtogeek.com/245510/how-to-change-excels-decimal-separators-from-periods-to-commas/), step-by-step with screenshots
- Microsoft Office Support: [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e), official documentation

### Format the cell(s) as text using a formula

- **Gain:** You can customize the decimal and thousands separator per cell
- **Loss:** The value is formatted (displayed) as type *text*. Although it can be right-aligned (to appear the same like the *number* type cells.

The [answer to similar question "Changing decimal separator with formula"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35925836/5730279) explains how to enter the formulas (with screenshots).

See also: [4 methods to change comma to decimal point in Excel](https://exceltable.com/en/formatting/change-comma-to-decimal-point)
https://exceltable.com/en/formatting/change-comma-to-decimal-point)